# Drag 'n Drop not working when using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to get the file from a drag 'n drop form. In the `drop` event I inserted the following:

```
var files = evt.dataTransfer.files[0];
```

When I use JavaSript for the event handlers, it works fine, but when I use JQuery, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined

How can I get the dropped file using JQuery?

#### JavaScript JSFiddle

#### JQuery JSFiddle

**JavaScript Snippet:**

```js
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    var files = evt.dataTransfer.files[0];
    console.log(files);
}

function handleDragOver(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
}

// Setup the dnd listeners.
var dropZone = document.getElementById('drop_zone');
dropZone.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver, false);
dropZone.addEventListener('drop', handleFileSelect, false);
```

```css
.example {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#drop_zone {
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 20pt bold 'Vollkorn';
    color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<output id="list"></output>
```

**JQuery Snippet**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#drop_zone').on('drop', function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();

        var files = evt.dataTransfer.files[0];
        console.log(files);
    });

    $('#drop_zone').on('dragover', function (evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

```css
.example {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#drop_zone {
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font: 20pt bold'Vollkorn';
    color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="drop_zone">Drop files here</div>
<output id="list"></output>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell jquery to include `dataTransfer` on the event object by adding this before you define your event handlers:

`$.event.props.push("dataTransfer");`

And then in the event handlers you can access the files with `evt.dataTransfer.files`.

(You may also want to use `var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;` rather than `var files = evt.dataTransfer.files[0];` if you want access to the entire list of dropped files, as opposed to just the first one.)

Comment: What exactly does `$.event.props.push` do?

Comment: `$.event.props` is an array of property names that jquery makes available on its event objects. `push()` is an array method that will add a new value to the end of the array. [Summary of jquery.event.props](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/#jquery-event-props-array)

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the original js event object

```
var files = evt.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
```

Comment: Why do I have to access it like that in JQuery and not in JavaScript